# SQL DAC and its dependencies are not installed

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am not able to install SQL Server 2012 Data Tier Framework (DacFx) from web platform installer on an Azure virtual machine, I get an error.

Is there any other way to install it on an Azure VM? Because when I am deploying my ASP.NET application to that Azure VM, I'm getting an error

> SQL provider DacFx is missing

Comment: ***WHAT*** error do you get?? Remember - we **cannot** see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **show us / tell us** the relevant info so we stand a chance to help you .....

Answer (score 0):

With this much of given problem statement, I can only suggest you to check the system requirements and dependencies.

As per this official [doc](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36842), Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework supports:

Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 2

**Dependencies:**

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework requires Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types, and Microsoft SQL Server Transact-SQL ScriptDom (SQLSysCLRTypes.msi and SQLDOM.msi)